# How to log backtrace to a file instead of popping it up and blocking following backtraces

Tags: debugging, debug, logging, backtrace

With emacs if there is a backtrace buffer open, new backtrace is ignored. I find it is unconvenient when I am trying to find out which function/hook changes a variable. I use debug-watch as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62579200/find-out-when-a-variable-is-changed-in-emacs
The problem is the variable changes happens after a backtrace buffer popup is impossible to know because of the backtrace blocking described above.

```
(debug-watch VARIABLE)
```

How can I make emacs popup as many backtrace buffers as possible or log the backtraces to a file?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with 'new backtrace is ignored' but you can exit the debugger and continue by pressing `c` (see the section [debugger commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Debugger-Commands.html) in the elisp manual).

Comment: It takes time between debugger popping up and me pressing c, during that time, there is possible other backtraces buried without notice. I have come across this situation. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this helps answer your request, but you can use function `backtrace` directly, to print a backtrace at any time to `standard-output` (which you can bind to a buffer etc.). `C-h f backtrace`:

> `backtrace` is a compiled Lisp function in `subr.el`.
>
> `(backtrace)1
>
> Print a trace of Lisp function calls currently active.
>
> Output stream used is value of `standard-output`.

See the Elisp manual, node [Internals of Debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Internals-of-Debugger.html), for more info about this, including and example information about variable `debugger-stack-frame-as-list`.

Comment: It surely helps in debugging one specific package. But often we don't know where is the problem. Like bookmark+ changing buffer local outline-regex and comment-start when saving bookmarks, while making outline-minor-mode crazy.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't recognize anything you say in your comment about Bookmark+ saving bookmarks. If you think you've found bugs, please report them specifically. AFAIK, Bookmark+ does nothing wrt `out-line-*` or `comment-start` when saving bookmarks or any other time. The only occurrence of `outline-*` in its code is in the doc string for `bookmark-after-jump-hook`, where it just suggests, as an example, that you can use the hook to unhide text in `outline-mode`. And there are no occurrences of `comment-start` in the code.

Comment: Bookmark+ seems to open the bookmark file in the background, and during processing of the file, it enables other mode that changes those variables. I disabled bookmark+ and everything is good now. I will look into it further later.

Comment: I think I have got the backtrace: https://gist.github.com/QiangF/706e6b103c668e87b8ae79fdc76700ea

Comment: Thanks, but I can't do anything with that really. You seem to have a lot of stuff going on, and it's not clear what - option customizations, key bindings, hydras, etc. Please (1) use `M-x bmkp-send-bug-report` to report the problem. But (2) do so with a *minimal recipe*, starting from `emacs -Q` to repro it.

Comment: You can also do `M-x debug-on-entry bookmark-save` and step through the debugger to see what happens. Use `d` for individual steps and `c` when you know you don't need to see the details within a step. With judicious use of `c` you can, in effect, bisect its use to drill into the relevant with details with `d`.

Comment: `bookmark-save` is short. You can also try commenting out parts of it, to perhaps see which parts you want to drill into, to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Enable `debug-on-error` and use at your own risk; I've given it the most rudimentary of testing, but wouldn't have the foggiest idea how robust this would be.

```el
(defun my-debug-to-file (&rest _args)
  (let ((inhibit-debugger t)
        (backtrace (backtrace-get-frames 'debug))
        (print-length nil))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert (backtrace-to-string backtrace))
      (insert "\n------------------------------------------------------\n\n")
      (append-to-file nil nil "/tmp/backtrace.log"))))

(advice-add 'debug :override #'my-debug-to-file)
;; (advice-remove 'debug #'my-debug-to-file)
```